# Self managing/releasing objects reported as "Potential leak of object" under Xcode -> Product -> Analyse

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

The Analyse feature of Xcode 4 is really great. The only problem is it thinks that objects that you initialise that are supposed to release themselves are reported as memory leaks.. ie how do you prevent it thinking this is a memory leak?

```
@interface BackgroundTaskThing

+ doBackgroundTask: (NSString*) something {
    BackgroundTaskThing* b = [[BackgroundTaskThing alloc] init];
    [b setSomething: something];
    [b runTask];
}

....

- (void)taskComplete {
    [self release];
}

@end
```

Comment: Bear in mind that self-releasing objects like this will break under ARC, should you ever decide to migrate your code.

Answer (score 4):

From [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#cl_diagnostics), section Controlling 'Static Analyzer Diagnostics':

```
#ifndef __clang_analyzer__
// Code not to be analyzed
#endif
```

(not that i encourage this, but it is one way to disable it)

Comment: That is one way.  However, an argument could be made that the object should generally not be releasing itself.  If it is in a processing queue somewhere, that queue (or block in the queue) should hold the reference.  It is, in general, a tricky problem.

Comment: It was a tough decision at the time related to if it should be done this way, however I remember reading some apple documentation at the time suggesting this was an ok practice under some circumstances.